# How to change Gnome Media Pop-Up Option for Removable Hard Drive

Tags: gnome, nautilus

When plugging in a USB hard drive, my Gnome Ubuntu 14.04 desktop opens a pop-up at the bottom of the screen. Until recently, this would allow me to either open the drive with Nautilus or eject it. I am not sure at what point exactly or why, but the pop-up has changed to display the "Disk Usage Analyzer" instead of Nautilus:

[image: pop-up menu for removable disk]

This is something I rarely want. Where can I change this back to giving me the option of opening Nautilus instead? The system settings in "Details > Removable media" don't show me options for hard drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening  because **Disk Usage Analyzer** has overridden the mime type through its .desktop file.

To correct it use the following command

`xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop  inode/directory`

After this you may need to restart the shell.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `r` to restart gnome-shell.

Comment: Great, thnx! Worked without a shell restart.